# Use of IBMid in user profile

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I noticed that 2 fields have been added to the SoftLayer user profile. The fields are managedByOpenIdConnectFlag and openIdConnectUserName. I have seen managedByOpenIdConnectFlag equal to true and openIdConnectUserName filed in. I have also seen managedByOpenIdConnectFlag equal to true and openIdConnectUserName not filled in. Where do I pick up the IBMid if managedByOpenIdConnectFlag equal to true and openIdConnectUserName is not filled in? Do I use the username field? What format will the username fiedl be _?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

This case:

> - "**managedByOpenIdConnectFlag**": true
> - "**openIdConnectUserName**": is not filled

happen when you have not accept the email's invitation yet, you need to accept this and the "**openIdConnectUserName**" will be automatic filled

Just in case, the username has the following format:

**"username": "225588_rubercuellar@mail.com"**

The **225588** is the **accountId**